# Print string while adding newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I'm trying to print out a string with embedded ruby to a webpage, if I use the following it ends up going off of the page.

```
<%= comment.body %>
```

I want to do something like this so that it automatically prints everything with new lines

```
<%= comment.body[0..136] %>
<%= "\n" %>
<%= comment.body[137..250] %>
```

I've done the following however it prints the characters with spaces between them and ignores spaces in the string.

```
<% for i in 0..comment.body.length do %>
<%= i %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply [use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) for this?

Comment: I didn't realise this was on option thanks! For anyone wondering about solving it I used a id tag in the <p id="commentBody"> then in the CSS I used #commentBody { word-wrap: break-word; }

Comment: Add this as a proper self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure but it can help you some how

```
<%=simple_format(comment.body, html_options={ class: 'your_class'}, options={})%>
```

for more details and modification [follow this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use HTML?

```
<% for i in 0..comment.body.length do %>
  <%= i %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not a good idea adding logic in views, less using Ruby `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using CSS

in HTML:

```
<p id="commentBody">
  ...
</p>
```

in CSS:

```
#commentBody {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```